# The method query(String, ResultSetExtractor<T>) in the type JdbcTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (String, BeanPropertyRowMapper)

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, junit4

I have a compile problem which is strange. I am not able to fix this. The same peice of code works fine in another project

```
org.mockito.Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(org.mockito.Matchers.anyString(), 
    org.mockito.Matchers.any(BeanPropertyRowMapper.class))).thenReturn(SOMELIST);
```

I am getting error as

> `The method query(String, ResultSetExtractor<T>) in the type JdbcTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (String, BeanPropertyRowMapper)`

But When I do this, I do not get any error. But I am not expecting this.

```
BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyClass> mapper = 
    new BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyClass>(MyClass.class);
org.mockito.Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(org.mockito.Matchers.anyString(), 
    mapper)).thenReturn(SOMELIST);
```

I am not sure if this is an Eclipse problem. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I see no problem. What type `jdbcTemplate` have?

Comment: @talex From the error message: "*`... in the type JdbcTemplate`*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [`BeanPropertyRowMapper<T>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html) is a generic interface, you should invoke `any()` like this:

```
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(Matchers.anyString(), 
    Matchers.<BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyClass>>any())).thenReturn(SOMELIST);
```

Comment: and how to write matchers for : new Integer[]{1}
My statement is: Mockito.when(j.query(Mockito.anyString(), Matchers.<BeanPropertyRowMapper<Integer>>any(), Matchers.<BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyClass>>any())).thenThrow(Exception.class);

Comment: Blech. This works for me also, but this is pretty distasteful. I wish there was a cleaner way.

Comment: What's also curious is that I only get this error from the Maven command-line build. Eclipse gives me several warnings on the original line, but no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check  for the dependency (spring jars) for version mismatch between projects